# What is the best practice for querying by ids on realm (== SQL IN query)

Tags: realm

I want to query User by multiple ids, like below.

```
realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", [1, 3, 5]).findAll()
```

What is the best practice of it?

I want to attach changeListner to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm currently doesn't support `IN` like SQLite, so you will have to do it manually:

```
RealmQuery<User> query = realm.where(User.class);
for (int i = 0; i < userIds.size(); i++) {
  if (i > 0) query.or();
  query.equalTo("id", userIds.get(i);
}
RealmResults<User> users = query.findAll();
```

There is a feature request here you can follow: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/841